# Unable to get css and image files in Themes webroot folder of cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I have a small problem with croogo CMS application while accessing of css and image files in app/Views/Themed/mythemename/webroot folder

```
   <?php  echo $this->Html->css(array('style'));?>
```

this gives me a css reference link in view-source

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/croogo/theme/mythemename/css/style.css" />
```

but when i click on this link(/croogo/theme/mythemename/css/style.css) it gives me that the url i'm trying to access is not found on the server

Comment: what are the permissions of those files/folders

Comment: I can read and write the files ,also i resolved that issue

Comment: Please update question with your answer or provide an official answer to your question because I have the same issue.

Comment: it was done by adding app/View/Themed/MyThemeName/webroot/theme.json file. @bowlerae

Comment: please go through it http://docs.croogo.org/1.5/en/designers/themes/json-file.html @bowlerae

Comment: Oh nvm this doesn't apply to me as I'm not using croogo. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was done by adding json file i.e.
`app/View/Themed/MyThemeName/webroot/theme.json file.` , please check 
the documentation [here](http://docs.croogo.org/1.5/en/designers/themes/json-file.html)

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I made a stupid mistake by misplacing the ending of a html tag.

Took ages to fix ;)

Check if your website is valid.

http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input